# Wordpress plugin / native Android & Dolphin browsers

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've got the mediaelement.js plugin installed in the current version of Wordpress.  The player works fine in Firefox on my Samsung S2 (Android 4.1), but in the native and Dolphin browsers I just see the icon for the play button and an outline of where the player should be.

Am I just SOL with these two browsers?  Or is there a fix or workaround?  Thanks.